# How to determine when text is selected [Android [EditText]]

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textselection

Is possible to determine when text is selected and when is not?

I was googling and I `find onSelectionChanged()` method or `setOnLongClickListener()` for determining when user `longClick`s the editText so when he made selection, but in both cases it can't help me with determining, when the user is not selecting any text (I could set button invisible)...

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {

              if (yourEditText.hasSelection()) {
                // if true, the text in the EditText is selected
              }

            return false;
          }
        });
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();
```

The `getSelectionStart()` method will return the start of the selection anchor/cursor or -1 if the user has not selected any text. You could try using this.

Comment: How I can test it every time? I should put it inside some loop? sry but i am new to programming for android :D :/

Comment: It depends on when you want to check. You can check it when you gain/lose focus, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can check editText.getSelectionStart() and editText.getSelectionEnd() and check if those values are:

- the same: user did not select text
- different: the user selected text

So:

```
int startSelection= textAbove.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection= textAbove.getSelectionEnd();

if (startSelection != endSelection) {
    ... DO SOMETHING ...
}
```