# How to add a button besides copy&paste, related to my app?..is this possible?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when user select text on android..some buttons will appear,like "copy & paste".
what i'm trying to do is to make my app show a button on the screen when text gets selected on my android phone.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489788/how-to-determine-when-text-is-selected-android-edittext

Comment: Is your query resolved?

Comment: Kamran Ahmed..No

Answer (score 0):

These answers are what you are looking for:

- [How to add item into popup copy/paste menu on a android selected `TextView`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41083050/1468093)
- [Making custom copy and paste menu appear when text is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20299320/1468093)